# TypeError: Object(...) is not a function - function to return deep copies of objects

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm having a `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` on the following scenario:

In order to initialize the state of a component with a given `Article` (that will be fetched from the backend in `componentDidMount`) I'm doing this

```
// ArticlePage.tsx
import { Article, buildArticle } from "../types";

// interfaces Props and State are properly defined above
export class ArticlePage extends Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      article: buildArticle(),
      //...
    }
  }
}
```

In the types module, I define the type for `Article`, a default article object to initialize state and a function to return deep copies of the default article object:

```
// types/Article.ts
import { buildUser, User } from ".";

export type Article = {
  id: number;
  user: User;
  // ...
};

const articleSkeleton: Article = {
  id: 0,
  user: buildUser(),  // <------ TypeError points to this line
  //...
}
export const buildArticle = (): Article => _.cloneDeep(articleSkeleton); // _ is lodash
```

Same thing for User

```
// types/User.ts
export type User = {
  id: number;
};

const userSkeleton: User = {
  id: 0,
}
export const buildUser = (): User => _.cloneDeep(userSkeleton); // _ is lodash
```

Both of them under a types directory with an index.ts like this:

```
// types/index.ts
export * from "./Article";
export * from "./User";
```

---

If I define the `articleSkeleton` object like this instead of using the `buildUser` function

```
// types/Article.ts
const articleSkeleton: Article = {
  id: 0,
  user: _.cloneDeep(userSkeleton), // deep clone the object directly here instead of calling the buildUser() function to do it
  //...
}
export const buildArticle = (): Article => _.cloneDeep(articleSkeleton); // _ is lodash
```

it works!

---

But in my head those are equivalent things...

Can someone explain me why they are not, why one works and the other doesn't?
Is what I am doing a bad practice and, if so, how should I handle this?

If I'm defining a type and a function to create objects of that type, would it be better to simply create a class instead?
What would be the pros and cons of that?

---

### Edit:

I've tried switching the order of the exports of `Article` and `User` in the `index.ts` file and it works now...

```
// types/index.ts
export * from "./User";
export * from "./Article";
```

Could it be that, when it was running the `buildUser()` function in `Article`, the `userSkeleton` object didn't exist yet?

Comment: Can you link to a codepen or the TS playground or something that shows the error? Also, how are you importing the `buildUser` function?

Comment: @JaredSmith, I've added the imports and an Edit at the bottom of the post. As for a playground I'll do it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the order of your constants is incorrect.

Move the declaration of `buildUser()` before `articleSkeleton`, or alternatively use a `function` instead of a `const`.

```ts
const buildUserOK = (): User => userSkeleton

const articleSkeleton = {
  id: 0,
  userError: buildUserError(),  
  userOk: buildUserOK(),
  userOk1: buildUserFun(),
  //...
}

type User = {
  id: number;
};

const userSkeleton: User = {
  id: 0,
}

const buildUserError = (): User => userSkeleton

function buildUserFun(): User { 
  return userSkeleton; 
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgVwJYBsAmBVCBTATgeQGkYBeGACgEoAuGLPUgPhgR1wGUBrbFbKcAFADQkWAENcUJMF5cefcKRgBvATBhI0tAAwAaNSzYBRXLhC5aiVJmOnzVXeoOs8%20TpeTp6BQg%20ds3AEYPa28AMQQwP3UAehiAOkSBAF8hKABPAAdsOjYlVXVNWjAEAFs4PABuFOrhcGhDPDlefjBab3yDIpg9FKERBqsvWzNcJSp2vJJmFw5uFsEBADNI4ClFIZs8CKiaXIZlGANcPgRcMEa5%20VbKo%20SgA)

Comment: Thanks. Using a `function` instead of a `const` didn't change anything, but declaring `buildUser()` before `articleSkeleton` (in my Edit I explain that I switched the order of the exports in `index.ts`) that did it!

Comment: Ah, I see - these definitions come from different files. It explains why `function` did not help.